# Illegal to renew cat's urinary food prescription if no yearly examination in WA State, USA?

Tags: medical, washington, pets

My friend's cat had emergency bladder stone surgery a couple of years ago. They put the cat on prescription urinary food my friend ordered online. The vet is refusing to renew the prescription because my friend hasn't brought cat in to see the doctor in the past year.

My friend says the vet is claiming it would be illegal to renew the prescription without seeing the cat. Is this true?

Comment: Next to the popular party drug “ecstasy”, cat urinary food is popular at raves.  This potential for abuse makes it important to regulate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is true. [Ch. 246-933-200 WAC](https://app.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=246-933&full=true) (1)(b)(i) requires that the veterinarian

> Has examined the animal(s) within the last year, or sooner if
> medically appropriate

in order to have a veterinary-client-patient relationship. Without that relationship, they cannot prescribe medication for an animal, because

> A veterinarian shall use or prescribe drugs only within the context of
> a veterinary-client-patient relationship.